# Applescript has a file change every time it's run via command line

Tags: automation, applescript

I have an apple script that I have included in my project that will send an email every time an automation report is generated. I call the apple script using the command line "osascript SendReportEmail.scpt" and this sends the email with the report attached. This is all working as intended however for whatever reason every time the apple script is run SourceTree is showing that a file change has been made to the applescript and I have no idea what it is. SourceTree is claiming that there is a change yet it's not showing the change. Does anyone know what the change is going on with the apple script in this case and a way to stop it?

Comment: https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=45122

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Mark Setchell and the link he provided I was able to address the issue macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=45122

By changing the file permissions is stopped that script for being able to make edits but the code in the file is still able to be excutted. Attached is a screenshot of how I changed the files permissions in order to resolve the issue.

[image: Screenshot of the fix]